# Xamarin.iOS. Appodeal. App Store rejected app because of old Yandex SDK in Appodeal plugin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, sdk, yandex, appodeal

Your app includes a version of an SDK from Yandex that violates the App Store Review Guidelines. The version of the Yandex SDK you are using in your app attempts to hide the use of private APIs.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please either remove the Yandex SDK entirely from your app, or revise your app to utilize version 2.9.8 or 3.1.2 of the Yandex SDK. Once you have made one of those changes, resubmit your binary for review.

> How to solve a problem?  I agree to remove the SDK. Tell me how to do
>   it

Comment: upgrade the plugin to the correct version

Comment: just replace Yandex SDK with the given version number.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS where to do it?

Comment: Refer this similar issue  http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/app-store-rejected-app-because-of-old-yandex-sdk-in-appodeal-plugin/43072  .You can update the package .